# String index out of range when sorting a dictionary of (string, float)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary mapping strings to floats that I want to sort. I can verify that the types of the values are correct, but when I try the sort I get an `IndexError` execption.

Below is a code snippet. The validation loop runs fine and then the call to sorted fails.

```
for k, v in metric.items():
    if not isinstance(v, float):
        print "Bad value %s for %s" % (k, str(v))
rank = sorted(metric, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)


---> 10     rank = sorted(metric, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
     11 

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Any idea why this happens?

Edit: this passes too with no problem:

```
for h in metric.iteritems():
    if not isinstance(operator.itemgetter(1)(h), float):
        print "Bad value %s for %s" % (h[0], h[1])
```

Answer (score 4):

You are only sorting the *keys* of the dictionary. Apparently some of your keys are only 1 character short, so you get an index error for `key[1]` (which is what `operator.itemgetter(1)(key)` would try and access).

If the expected output is a sorted sequence of keys, look up the value from the dictionary:

```
rank = sorted(metric, key=metric.get, reverse=True)
```

If you expected a sequence of `(key, value)` pairs, sort `metric.items()`:

```
rank = sorted(metric.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

When sorting the `dict.items()` sequence, `item[1]` refers to the value.

Comment: Thanks, yes! Totally missed that. I needed the .items() call.